# Unloading Dialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im little unsure on how the ShowDialog works

Im doing this

```
NewReportDialog nrDialog = new NewReportDialog();
nrDialog.DataContext = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INewReportViewModel>();
nrDialog.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
nrDialog.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
bool? dialogResult = nrDialog.ShowDialog();


  if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
   {
    Console.WriteLine(((INewReportViewModel)nrDialog.DataContext).ReportName);
    Console.WriteLine(((INewReportViewModel)nrDialog.DataContext).SelectedSite);
   }
```

What puzzles me is that i can still read the DataContext after the dialog has been closed. How do i make sure that the dialog is unloaded or do i have to rely on the garbage collector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext is an arbitrary object. In your case, it's whatever is resolved by the call to **ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance()**. When the dialog closes on your screen, the object representing its DataContext is still in scope for the code you've shown.

This is useful, because it allows you to do something within that dialog and then, upon its termination, extract some data that was "set" within the dialog (just like you're doing with the **ReportName** and **SelectedSite** properties).

Once the dialog that holds the reference to the **INewReportViewModel** falls out of scope (exiting the method in which the dialog is created, for example), you can assume it is "gone" and the GC will handle it.

Comment: Thanks to both , not sure how i missed that

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is not removed from memory because you have a reference to it, and therefore the garbage collector won't delete it.

You could assign null to `nrDialog` after you're done with it, but you would still be relying on the garbage collector.